# Exim piping for forwarding to rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, exim

I am using Exim. I am trying to "send" all emails to a rails controller, but unfortunately I have no experience with Piping emails. Any help with the configuration of Exim is welcome. What i want is that Exim should forward all emails that are going to "bounce", because no such user exists, to the script

Comment: I would suggest this would be better asked in ServerFault as it's not actually the programming aspect but the Exim config that's the issue?